# ошибка,модуль принимает не более 2 аргументов

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import filters as BaseFilter 
from aiogram.types import Message


class IsMedia(BaseFilter):
    is_media: bool

    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        self.is_media = message.media_group_id is not None
        return self.is_media
```

TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Когда модуль стал вызываться с аргументами? Скрипт выше разве воспроизведёт эту ошибку?

Comment: да воспроизвёл, как решить это?

Comment: Нет ваш скрипт не подходит под минимально воспроизводимый пример. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example